# Xcode link binary with libraries and unexpected file type

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-errors, dylib, instantclient

I want to use Oracle **instantclient** libraries for C++. I use Xcode as an IDE. I added the **occi** library by Project > Build Phase > Link binary with libraries. I am having the following warning and error at compilation.

> warning: skipping file '/Users/user/Library/Oracle/instantclient_12_2/libocci.dylib.12.1' (unexpected file type 'text.man' in Frameworks & Libraries build phase)
>
> error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "oracle::occi::Environment::createEnvironment(oracle::occi::Environment::Mode, void*, void* (*)(void*, unsigned long), void* (*)(void*, void*, unsigned long), void (*)(void*, void*))", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o

Certainly, the error is due to the warning. It looks like the issue is coming from the version number (.12.1) at the end of the file after the ".dylib" (I don't have the issue for other libraries in the same folder for which the name does not have the version number after the file extension).

The **instantclient** library can be downloaded [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html). You will see that the downloaded folder will contain files **libocci.dylib** and **libocci.dylib.12.1**. The first one being a link to the second one:

```
ls -l *occi*
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 user  wheel       18 Mar 23 14:01 libocci.dylib -> libocci.dylib.12.1
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 user  wheel  1465312 Jan  9  2018 libocci.dylib.12.1
```

I tried with the two files and Xcode will automatically use **libocci.dylib.12.1**.

#### Questions:

- Why the version number is set after the `.dylib` extension?
- Why the compiler does not recognize the file type?
- What to do in order the compiler to recognize the file type?

Comment: Have you tried renaming the file?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to env vars in product>scheme>edit scheme.

Also add -locci and -lclntsh to "other linker flags" in build settings.